# Can view Google Analytics real time report of localhost?

Tags: google-analytics

I followed [this code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#localhost).
How can I view Google Analytics real time report for localhost?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a few hours to reflect the data in the dashboard. Just wait a few hours and try again.

Comment: I believe OP was asking about how to see data in RT, as opposed to Standard Reports.